# Google domains not mapping to my app in GCloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-domain-api

I have installed my app in the google compute engine and it is running perfectly fine at http://104.155.177.45:80/ . I have made this as a Node js app. But when i try to point this IP to my domain it is not working fine as it would. My domain is http://www.homedyou.com. I have done pointing the A Record to this IP address. How to resolve it.

Comment: The instructions for [setting up LAMP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/setting-up-lamp) on Google Cloud include a section about assigning domain names, "Setting up DNS", about half way down.

Comment: Also, you haven't configured the sub-domain "www". While www.homedyou.com doesn't work, homedyou.com does.

Comment: Thanks @Ourborus But any reference on how to configure "www."  subdomain.

Comment: It's largely dependent on your DNS service provider. Generally, you want to set up an A record for "www" pointing to the same IP. You may also need to authorize it on the Google side.

Comment: Thanks for your response.... It made my work easier...!

Comment: @Ouroborus can you add the answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: @PaulR.Nash Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comments to an answer, as requested:

The instructions for [setting up LAMP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/setting-up-lamp) on Google Cloud include a section about assigning domain names, "Setting up DNS", about half way down.

It appears the "www" sub-domain isn't configured. www.homedyou.com doesn't work, but homedyou.com does.

Configuring this involves setting up an A record for "www" in your DNS configuration pointing to the same IP. How you go about doing this is largely dependant on your DNS service provider. It may also need to be authorized on the Google side.